# Translation with less words can inflict SEO?

Tags: seo, translation

Can I translate a website in a foreign language reducing the content *(in the translated version)* from the original language?
For example, the original website in English has 30.000 words; instead the version translated in German will have 18.000 words *(although maintaining the amount of 250/300 words for each page translated)*; several *(not many)* H2 and H3 couldn't be in the translated version *(but not necessarily)*.
Can this less amount of words inflict heavily SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google will reward each version of the page on its own merits, in fact, it's common if not expected that some languages have fewer words or more words than one compared to another. This also means more or less headers, again, each version is treated separately.

As long as you DO NOT use auto-translate software then you will be okay.